# Como arrendondar para a dezena mais próxima?

Tags: javascript, matemática

Como posso fazer para arredondar um número para a dezena mais próxima em JavaScript?

**Por exemplo:**

O usuário digita 11, aí arredondaria para 20; o usuário digita 11.5, arredondaria para 20; e assim por diante.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
function arredonda(n) {
    return n % 10 ? n + 10 - n % 10 : n;
}
```

ou

```
function arredonda(n) {
    return Math.ceil(n / 10) * 10;
}
```

Pelo que eu entendi, se n = 10, deve retornar 10; se n = 11, deve retornar 20.

Answer (score 5):

Em geral, usa-se os métodos `ceil` (teto) e `floor` (piso) para arredondar para o **inteiro** mais próximo, mas como você quer arredondar na direção de uma grandeza diferente (no caso uma dezena) é preciso fazer alguma adaptação:

```
function teto(numero, arredondarPara) {
    if ( !arredondarPara ) arredondarPara = 1;
    return Math.ceil(numero / arredondarPara) * arredondarPara;
}

function piso(numero, arredondarPara) {
    if ( !arredondarPara ) arredondarPara = 1;
    return Math.floor(numero / arredondarPara) * arredondarPara;
}

teto(7.2); // 8
teto(7.2, 10); // 10

teto(7.2, 0.1); // 7.2
teto(7.2, 2); // 8
teto(7.2, 3); // 9
teto(7.2, 4); // 8
teto(7.2, 5); // 10
teto(7.2, 6); // 12
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente assim:

```javascript
function aproxima(valor) {
    if(valor%10 == 0) return valor;
    var round = Math.ceil(valor);
    while(round%10 != 0) round++;
    return round;
}
```

Comment: Vou testar e já retorno

Comment: Como faria para pegar o menor valor mais próximo? Exemplo: valor = 5 e pegar o número 1?

Answer (score 0):

Com essa função ele vai pegar a primeira maior dezena

```
function arredonda(x){
while (aux < x){
aux= aux+10;
};
aux= aux - x + 10;
return aux + x;
```

e esta próxima função irá arredondar para a dezena mais próxima

```
function arredonda_mais_perto(x){
while (aux < x){
aux= aux+10;
};
aux= aux - x + 10;
if (aux > 5)
return aux + x;
else
return aux - x;
```

Comment: `arredonda(99999999)` será um pouco lento, não? Além do mais seria bom limitar o escopo do `aux`, o declarando local.