# Como arredondar para a dezena mais próxima em PHP?

Tags: php

Vi essa pergunta aqui no Stack Overflow [Como arrendondar para a dezena mais próxima?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1644/como-arrendondar-para-a-dezena-mais-pr%C3%B3xima?rq=1) e a achei muito interessante.

Só que a pergunta se trata de JavaScript.

Como eu poderia fazer arredondar um número para a dezena mais próxima em PHP?

Exemplo:

```
11  => 20
23  => 30,
2.5 => 10
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você gostaria de deixar números a partir do 0 sempre em dezenas?
Se sim, veja se ajuda esse exemplo:

```
$num = 11;
$num = ceil($num / 10) * 10;
```

Comment: Ajuda sim, exatamente isso. É só utilizar isso numa função e está de boa!

Answer (score 2):

A que uso aqui é:

```
function roundByValue($valor, $valorArredondamento){
    if($valorArredondamento != 0){
        $valor = round($valor/$valorArredondamento)*$valorArredondamento;
    }
    return $valor;
}

// pr = print_r
pr(roundByValue(10.5, 1));      // 11
pr(roundByValue(10.23, 0.5));   // 10
pr(roundByValue(10.27, 0.5));   // 10.5
pr(roundByValue(10.07, 0.25));  // 10
pr(roundByValue(10.74, 0.10));  // 10.7
pr(roundByValue(10.17, 0.75));  // 10.5
```

Comment: Esse segundo parâmetro é para definir se arredonda pra cima ou pra baixo?

Comment: Na verdade não, é para definir o multiplicador de arredondamento, por exemplo, eu quero arredondar a cada `0.25`, ou a cada `0.5`, assim ele arredonda para o numero mais próximo do multiplicador de arredondamento.

Comment: Então é quase o que eu falei, se você entendeu o que quis dizer com "para baixo" e "para cima"

Comment: Não pois, como comentei é o multiplicador, em um exemplo `roundByValue(10.27, 0.5)` o resultado sera `10.5`, pois o multiplicador é `0.5`, ja em `roundByValue(10.27, 0.15)` o resultado sera `10.3` pois o multiplicador é `0.15`.